# Как реализовать горизонтальный скролл одного блока?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите как реализовать такой скролл?
Как реализовать такую анимацию как на сайте https://k24moscow.ru/en/location/
вот этого блока

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может есть библиотеки такие?
scrollmagic подключать не хочу т.к. анимация нужна только для одного блока

Comment: Понял о чем вы. Вопрос для меня был не понятен. Свой ответ удалю

Comment: Сделано очень просто, после события прокрутки колеса, мы просто меняем transform: translateX(%); 
Тут не нужны левые библиотеки, клава js и css.

Comment: Изменил ответ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let element = document.getElementById("scroll");
let cnt = 0





document.addEventListener('wheel', function(event){
    event = event || window.event;
    var y = event.deltaY || event.detail || event.wheelDelta,val=0.1,min = 0,max=0;    

    if(y > 0){      
        cnt = cnt - 20;  
        element.style.transform = 'translate(' + cnt + '%)'
    }
    if(y < 0){
        cnt = cnt + 20;
        element.style.transform = 'translate(' + cnt + '%)'
    }
});
```

```css
#scroll{
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  float: right;
  transform: translate();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id = "scroll"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="./js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Что-то типа такого. На коленках

Comment: Единственное это понятно, что требуется доп блок который даст скролить только внутри него, те не задевая основной скролл браузера

Comment: Спасибо, дальше думаю сам сделаю